# Facebook Graph API for pages using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve the conversations that the page had with it's users/visitors. I was able to retrieve the conversations for the page using the below call. I do have the right page access token in the 'pgAccessToken' variable.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:pgAccessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[params setObject:@"fields" forKey:@"fields"];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/conversations"
                              parameters:nil tokenString:pgAccessToken
                              version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Output : %@", result);
}];
```

I was able to receive a list of conversations.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2015-12-12T02:24:21+0000",
      "id": "m_mid.1449888061289:b3ec94g1ec0729d776"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2015-12-12T02:23:08+0000",
      "id": "m_mid.1449887988645:94905084ecfdf89812"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/t_mid.1448167619182:200955bd99614aa136/messages?format=json&access_token={MYACCESSTOKEN}&limit=25&since=1449887061&__paging_token={MYPAGINGTOKEN}&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/t_mid.1448167619182:2009335d99614aa136/messages?format=json&access_token={MYACCESSTOKEN}&limit=25&until=1448167619&__paging_token={MYPAGINGTOKEN}"
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to receive messages in the conversation. Which I can get by hitting the node '{conversation-id}/messages' but it just gives me a timestamp and message id as part of the response.

What I want is not just the time stamp and message id, but instead the from, to and message contents. I tried the Graph API Explorer but it would still return the same data when I use the following different nodes.

/{conversation-id}/messages

/{message-id}

Can any one help ?

++++UPDATE++++ 
FIGURED IT OUT. PASTED BELOW IS THE ANSWER IF SOMEBODY ELSE COMES ACROSS THE SAME ISSUE.

Finally figured this out after a few tries with Graph API Explorer tool on facebook developer page.

The way to get more fields is by supplying the fields I wanted in addition to the default that were being sent to me.

```
NSString *pgAccessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"]; //I have my page accesstoken stored here.

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"message_count,updated_time,participants,snippet" forKey:@"fields"];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/conversations"
                              parameters:params tokenString:pgAccessToken
                              version:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

__weak MessagesTableViewController *weakSelf = self;
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Output : %@", result);
   //Process your result here, add to local array, reload table etc.
}];
```

Comment: Yeap, that's a change made in v2.4 of the Graph API where you have to explicitly specify the fields that you need. It is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v23tov24 I'd recommend posting your edit as an answer.